# Add-PnPNavigationNode in a foreach loop keeps returning format-default error

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, azure-automation

I am running the following PnP script within Azure Automation (PowerShell 7.1):

```
$QLdocLibraries = @(
    "Library 1",
    "Library 2"
)

foreach ($item in $QLdocLibraries) {
    $libraryUrl = "$item/"
    Write-Host "Defined '$libraryUrl' to use as an URL"
    
    try {
        # Add the library to Quick Launch
        Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title $item -Url $libraryUrl -Location "QuickLaunch" -ErrorAction Stop
      
    } 
    catch {
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

The code adds the first item of the array to the Quicklaunch, but not the second. It does not even go into the catch statement on the 2nd loop. It just gives me the following response:

format-default: The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Anyone have experience with this and can help me with it? I am a bit lost..

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace with the following script

```
$libraryUrl = "/" + $item
```